# Как убрать пробел после name?

Tags: python, синтаксис

```
name = input()          
print ("Hello,", name,'!')
```

input = Harry
Выводит : `Hello, Harry !`
А должно :`Hello, Harry!`

Comment: Можно заменить запятые на плюсики

Comment: Ещё можно так: `print(..., sep='')`

Comment: Прив вводе имени Harry в консоли неставь пробел после имени а нажми enter

Comment: @evgenik, при выполнении кода из вопроса пробел перед восклицательными знаком будет в любом случае добавляться, поэтому ваш совет не работает.

Answer (score 8):

Можно поступить так:

```
name = input()
print('Hello, {}!'.format(name))
```

Или так:

```
print('Hello, ' + name + '!')
```

Или так:

```
print(f'Hello, {name}!')
```

Или так:

```
print('Hello, %s!' % name)
```

Comment: Ну тогда уж и про `sep=''` напиши :)

Comment: @diraria Тут в этом нет смысла. Больше толку от этого при распаковке.

Comment: Почему нет смысла?) И расскажи, что такое распаковка, пожалуйста

Comment: Добавь тогда и форматирование через `%`, раз `format` упомянул :)

Comment: @diraria ну что бы убрать пробел я бы не рекомендовал `sep` писать, про распаковку читайте в интернетах.

Comment: @gil9red добавил :)

Comment: @diraria, например `print(*'123')` и `print(*'123', sep=', ')`, тоже самое можно и для, к примеру, списков применить

Comment: @gil9red понял, спасибо!

Comment: стоит упомянуть какой из вариантов является более предпочтительным (это не очевидно). Если формат в виде константы известен как в этом случае, то `f'Hello, {name}!'` наиболее ясный (и вероятно самый эффективный) вариант. Поддерживается в Python 3.6+ Остальные варианты менее читаемы: `'Hello, {}!'.format(name)`.  Если больше одного имени или не строковая переменная, то  `'Hello, ' + name + '!'` ещё хуже. Вариант с `%s` может иметь проблемы если `name` это кортеж (из-за бага к примеру иногда), и на Питоне 2 были ещё более тонкие отличия от `''.format()` кода (неявные преобразования `uni<->str`).

Answer (score 5):

Пробел добавляется благодаря дефолтному аргументу `sep` (спс за напоминание от `diraria`), а функция `print`, напомню, имеет такое описание:

```
def print(self, *args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None)
```

Поэтому, достаточно добавить:

```
print("Hello, ", name, '!', sep='')
# Hello, Harry!
```

---

**PS.**

Но лучше выводить сообщения с параметрами через форматирование строк как это было показано [в ответе Pavel Durmanov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/713665)

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input()
print("Hello, " ,name,end="!")

hery
Hello,  Harry!
```

Comment: чтобы дополнить ответ, нажмите [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Прошло всего то  5 лет 1 месяц со дня как был задан вопрос, и я в процессе обучения столкнулся с этой задачкой. Ответ был такой:

```
name = input ()
print("Hello, "+name+'!')
```

Comment: хоть это и работает, но стиль не для питона. И дело тут только стиля и вкуса. Хотя при дальнейшем погружении можно будет найти и проблемы со скоростью для f строк и еще более интересные вещи

Comment: Думаю что автор задачи рассчитывал на необходимость поиска различных вариантов, включая `sep=''`, для обучения.

Comment: да я и не против) Я к тому, что надо использовать то решение, которое подходит